# Open More than 1 intent (Activity )

Tags: android

I have created 2 activities. It force closes. Why?

```
05-12 23:26:07.041: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5170): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
05-12 23:26:07.051: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5170): java.lang.VerifyError: yaraby.y.yaraby$1
05-12 23:26:07.051: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5170):     at yaraby.y.yaraby.onCreate(yaraby.java:44)
05-12 23:26:07.051: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5170):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1127)
05-12 23:26:07.051: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5170):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2231)
05-12 23:26:07.051: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5170):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2284)
05-12 23:26:07.051: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5170):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:112)
05-12 23:26:07.051: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5170):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1692)
05-12 23:26:07.051: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5170):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-12 23:26:07.051: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5170):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-12 23:26:07.051: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5170):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3948)
05-12 23:26:07.051: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5170):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-12 23:26:07.051: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5170):     at  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-12 23:26:07.051: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5170):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:782)
 05-12 23:26:07.051: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5170):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:540)
 05-12 23:26:07.051: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5170):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

if any one have a solution please tell me and i can send my project code to be checked

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    inputfld=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.input);
    Text=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.view);
    Enter=(Button)findViewById(R.id.enter);
    Connect=(Button)findViewById(R.id.connect);

    Text.append( "\n about to create a socket");    


    txt=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt);
    next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);   

    next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(yaraby.this, HelloItemizedOverlay.class);
 yaraby.this.startActivity(i);
//              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "haaaaaaaaaaa",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

this the first Oncreate for first class

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main2);

    Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button02);
    next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    private String key;

    public void onClick(View view) {
        next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(yaraby.this,     HelloItemizedOverlay.class);
            yaraby.this.startActivity(i);

  next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { is the 44 line !!
```

Comment: Post the code from your `onCreate` method please.

Comment: If you have a `VerifyError`, this means that there's something wrong with the classes. You should post the portion of the class which generates this error, otherwise it is only possible to make guesses.

Comment: Did you add both the activities to your manifest file??

Comment: @Malcolm so lets take a wild guess..

Comment: yup in mainfeist i added both !!

Comment: can any 1 accept me to send the project file to his mail to check it up please due to its important to me ?

Comment: which line is the error on?? Add try catch to your code and run it in debug mode ...you might get some ideas

Comment: can i send to mail or atteched the project here ?

Comment: next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { this line 44

Comment: why this is an error line 44 ?? any assumption

Comment: Guys any help to send the project any any one try to help me

Comment: please post the complete command from line 44, not just the beginning (i.e., the whole listener) Also, make sure that you did not add/delete any lines between running the logcat and sending the code. The "assumption" that the error is on line 44 comes from the logcat itself: **at yaraby.y.yaraby.onCreate(yaraby.java:44)** (the last number is the line number in that file, in this case, 44)

Comment: @ Aleadam  do you want me to add all the code ?!!!

Comment: You have two classes posted. We only need the one in which the error is happening. I believed you named one class `yaraby`. (your logcat says `yaraby.java:44` which indicates the class name `yaraby`. I believe you posted line 44 from the other class that you have. So in your question, please note which line is 44 in the class that has `R.layout.main` for it's layout (since you already specified line 44 for the class that has `R.layout.main2` for it's layout).